# This CSS definition for ordered list <ol> gives "Unknown property name'. Is the syntax wrong?

Tags: css, html-lists

I'm re-using some code from codepen to spruce up a list. Currently I'm getting an error in the browser Element's panel: "Unknown property name," for everything after the '> li {}'

Does this code require a pre-processor perhaps? Is there a way to revise to make it work?
Many thanks!

Here is the code:

```
ol.gradient-list {
  counter-reset: gradient-counter;
  list-style: none;
  margin: 1.75rem 0;
  padding-left: 1rem;
  > li {       <======= Error starts here
    background: white;
    border-radius: 0 0.5rem 0.5rem 0.5rem;
    @extend %boxshadow;
    counter-increment: gradient-counter;
    margin-top: 1rem;
    min-height: 3rem;
    padding: 1rem 1rem 1rem 3rem;
    position: relative;
    &::before,
    &::after {
      background: linear-gradient(135deg, $blue 0%,$green 100%);
      border-radius: 1rem 1rem 0 1rem;
      content: '';
      height: 3rem;
      left: -1rem;
      overflow: hidden;
      position: absolute;
      top: -1rem;
      width: 3rem;
    }
    &::before {
      align-items: flex-end;
      @extend %boxshadow;
      content: counter(gradient-counter);
      color: $black;
      display: flex;
      font: 900 1.5em/1 'eurostile-mn';
      justify-content: flex-end;
      padding: 0.125em 0.25em;
      z-index: 1;
    }
    @for $i from 1 through 5 {
      &:nth-child(10n+#{$i}):before {
        background: linear-gradient(135deg, rgba($green, $i * 0.2) 0%,rgba($yellow, $i * 0.2) 100%);
      }
    }
    @for $i from 6 through 10 {
      &:nth-child(10n+#{$i}):before {
        background: linear-gradient(135deg, rgba($green, 1 - (($i - 5) * 0.2)) 0%,rgba($yellow, 1 - (($i - 5) * 0.2)) 100%);
      }
    }
    + li {
      margin-top: 2rem;
    }
  }
```

Here is the console image:
[image]

Comment: That's not valid CSS, but looks like SCSS or SASS (or any other CSS preprocessor)

Comment: It is SCSS. I found an online converter to convert it to CSS. Then I was able to incorporate it just fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's [SCSS](https://sass-lang.com/), it must first be [converted to CSS](https://sass-lang.com/guide) before it can be understood by browsers.